# Rear projection effect in The Hateful Eight

Tags: effects, the-hateful-eight

Do you think that the rear projection effect used in the movie The Hateful Eight during the ride to Red Rock was used just due to economical reasons or was meant as some sort of a stylistic effect?

Comment: I don't suppose there's an image you can find that shows what you're talking about? I haven't seen the film but I'm having a difficult time imagining what is being described.

Comment: +1: It was something I couldnt ignore when I watched it. @Catija: When you are looking out from inside the carriage it is very obvious that the snow and the trees dont move at the same pace as the carriage.

Comment: I imagine it's very deliberate. Tarantino loves adding that kind of deliberate anachronism as a nod to the old style films which used the same techniques.  You can see he does similar things in several films - most noticeably Death Proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question was "do you think...", so that's how I will address it.

It was a practical choice, not stylistic.   For reference, here is a screenshot of when it's at its worst:

[image]

This part of the film features (by my count) 4 different angles, including the one shown here.   Two of the four include clear shots of the moving background.    Given that we also know Tarantino used Ultra Panavision 70 lenses to shoot the scenes, I feel confident saying that these shots are done on a soundstage not in a real stagecoach.    Here is a shot showing the crew standing outside the coach with the camera for a still shot.

[image]

The space required to affix the camera for the internal shots, frankly doesn't seem to be there.

For clarity on my post, can I offer it was *both* practical and stylistic?   In this case Tarantino likely couldn't film with a moving stagecoach on location, but he does use rear projection stylistically as well, so he chose that style as a result of the limitation.

Comment: I haven't seen the film but I assume from the question it was fairly obviously rear screen projection - this indicates to me that it was largely a stylistic choice.  There's a scene in Pulp Fiction with Bruce Willis riding in the back of a car that very obviously uses rear projection as a stylistic choice.  Having said that it could primarily be a practical choice but to make it obviously look like rear projection is clearly stylist.